# How do I calculate the elapsed time from a Java Swing Timer

Tags: java, swing, time

I have a Timer instance from javax.swing.Timer, I'm trying to calculate the time remaining from a cooldown because I'm using it for commands.

I'm testing it with a 15 second cooldown. The cooldown works fine but I want to be able to post how much time is remaining for when I get to larger cooldowns like 5 - 10 minutes etc.
I want to say like
00:00:15 remaining
00:00:14 remaining
00:00:13 remaining
etc

I know I'm missing something here.

Below I've put the code im using to calculate the elapsed time and the conversion from Millis to HMS
When the command is called the start time is set to currentTimeMillis()

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

public void callWithCooldown(int cooldown) {
        ActionListener callMethod = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                enable();
            }
        };

        boolean didCall = call();
        if(!didCall) return;

        disable();
        this.timer = new Timer(cooldown, callMethod);
        timer.setRepeats(false);
        this.startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        timer.start();

        String notification = "Cooldown activated for " + MathHelper.millisecondsToHMS(cooldown) + "!";
        System.out.println(notification);
        notify(notification);
    }

public String elapsedTime() {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long endTime = (startTime + cooldown);
        int elapsed = (int) (endTime - now);
        System.out.println(elapsed);
        return millisecondsToHMS(Math.abs(elapsed));
    }

    public static String millisecondsToHMS(int milliseconds) {
        String time = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(milliseconds),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(milliseconds) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(milliseconds)),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(milliseconds) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(milliseconds)));
        return time;
    }
```

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Comment: Then use a Timer with *1 second* updates.

Comment: I can't get it to properly tell me how much time is remaining. Without needing to use a second timer ideally

Comment: The elapsed time is just returning "00:00:15 remaining!" and nothing else when converted to HMS.

Comment: Please add a [MRE], with input, expected and observed output.

Answer (score 1):

You can create two `Timer` objects. One for the total time waiting, and one for the count down:

```
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Main {

    private static long START;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final int totalSeconds = 15;

        final Timer tm = new Timer(1000, e -> {
            System.out.println("Seconds remaining: " + (totalSeconds * 1000 - System.currentTimeMillis() + START) / 1000d);
        });

        START = System.currentTimeMillis();

        new Timer(totalSeconds * 1000, e -> {
            tm.stop();
            System.out.println("Finished!");
        }).start();

        tm.start();

        //Wait for the program to execute:
        try { Thread.sleep((totalSeconds + 2) * 1000); } catch (final InterruptedException ix) {}
    }
}
```

Although I think `Timer` is not exactly the most accurate solution for such a problem (depending on how accurate you want it to be), but it is a simple one.

Or in your code, this could be:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Main {
    private long startTime;
    private final Timer total, countDown;

    public Main() {
        countDown = new Timer(1000, e -> System.out.println(elapsedTime()));
        total = new Timer(2000, e -> { //Defaults to 2000 ms for example.
            countDown.stop();
            enable();
        });
        total.setRepeats(false);
    }

    public void enable() {
        System.out.println("Enable!");
    }

    public void callWithCooldown(int cooldownSeconds) {
        total.setInitialDelay(cooldownSeconds * 1000);
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        total.start();
        countDown.start();
    }

    public String elapsedTime() {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long endTime = (startTime + total.getInitialDelay());
        int elapsed = (int) (endTime - now);
        return millisecondsToHMS(Math.abs(elapsed));
    }

    public static String millisecondsToHMS(int milliseconds) {
        String time = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(milliseconds),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(milliseconds) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(milliseconds)),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(milliseconds) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(milliseconds)));
        return time;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final int seconds = 15;
        new Main().callWithCooldown(seconds);
        //Let the program run for 'seconds' seconds at least to show all messages:
        try { Thread.sleep((seconds + 2) * 1000); } catch (final InterruptedException ix) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: @DRAGONMASTER412 glad it was what you were looking for.

Comment: @DRAGONMASTER412 you can do this with only one Timer also (for example by counting down every 1 second and adding a counter to reach 15). But that would be even less accurate (because as you can see from printing the count down time, there is a small incrementing delay of 2ms between calls of the Action of the Timer). So after 1 hour for example (with the single Timer), that 2ms/s would reach 7200ms and so on. Anyway.

Comment: @DRAGONMASTER412 this delay is not true however for the two Timers approach, because the *total* timer stops the *countDown* one. The only problem now with the two timers is that at some point after 500 calls the *countDown* timer would skip a full second in the printing statements. So that's why I print the result of remaining seconds as a floating number rather than an int.